# How to automatically change record in database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I need to automatically change a record in my database on a specific date and time.

Example: When the date and time is 01/12/2012 17:15:00 I want some record to automatically be set to 1. Is there any solution to this?

(I am using Rails 3.2.6)

**Update 30.11.12 - 13:06**

The real problem is that I have a datetime record in my database, when the date and time in this record exceeds todays date and time - then I want another record to be set to 1. Is there any way I can make an `if` statement, or something, somewhere in my controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use whenever https://github.com/javan/whenever to set up a cron job for you

Whenever has an easy syntax in its `schedule.rb` file to let you run tasks "whenever" you like

From their readme:

```
every 3.hours do
  runner "MyModel.some_process"
  rake "my:rake:task"
  command "/usr/bin/my_great_command"
end

every 1.day, :at => '4:30 am' do
  runner "MyModel.task_to_run_at_four_thirty_in_the_morning"
end

every :hour do # Many shortcuts available: :hour, :day, :month, :year, :reboot
  runner "SomeModel.ladeeda"
end

every :sunday, :at => '12pm' do # Use any day of the week or :weekend, :weekday
  runner "Task.do_something_great"
end

every '0 0 27-31 * *' do
  command "echo 'you can use raw cron syntax too'"
end

# run this task only on servers with the :app role in Capistrano
# see Capistrano roles section below
every :day, :at => '12:20am', :roles => [:app] do
  rake "app_server:task"
end
```

Comment: Ok, but the real problem is that I have a datetime record in my database, when the date and time in this record exceeds todays date and time - then I want another record to be set to 1. Isnt there any way I can make an `if` statement somewhere in my controller?

Comment: No because code in your controller is only run when a web page is hit

Answer (score 4):

I can see a few possible options here. It depends on your assumptions/constraints.

Possible assumptions (ordered by increasing difficulty to implement):

1) the data does not need to be correct in the database, but the next time somebody takes a look at the data, we fix it accordingly
2) the data does not need to be correct in the database, but e.g. within a definable time-interval
3) the data needs to be correct in the database at all times

Let me go over these in more detail

### The data will appear correct, next time somebody looks at the data

This is actually pretty easy. When retrieving the data to be shown, then check if certain conditions/times have past, and set flags accordingly.

For the user it is actually not relevant when the flags were set correctly, but everytime a user will look at the data, the flags will be set correctly.

### The data will be correct inside a given time-interval

A simple case is to check every hour, every half hour, once per day and set or fix the states of items that need to be changed.

To accomplish this you would use a cron job or a gem like [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever)

This is a very simple approach and will assure your data will be correct in an acceptable/given interval (if your problem has such an interval of course).

### The data must be set at the correct time

Here I see two options, either for each item that needs to change state at a given time, schedule a 
task using the same options as before: cron or the whenever gem. This would work, but I am not entirely sure if cron is the best solution for scheduling a lot of 1-off jobs.

Alternatively, a very clean solution is to use a gem like [DelayedJob](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job). This gem is mostly used to offload tasks to the background, e.g. for tasks that need a bit more time processin. But you can also use it to execute tasks in the near future, at a very specific time.

```
  def change_flag_when_needed
    # change the flag
  end
  # 5.minutes.from_now will be evaluated when change_flag_when_needed is called
  handle_asynchronously :in_the_future, :run_at => Proc.new { 5.minutes.from_now }
```

Whenever you will call `change_flag_when_needed`, it will evaluate the given block, which now contains `5.minutes.from_now`, but could as well calculate the actual time when it should be performed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I did go for the whenever gem and it worked, but I finally added a endDate record combined with a long query that solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

use cron job on linux server and set time for run script

Comment: Try expanding more your answer.